# Should the enableHighAccuracy make a difference when set in "geolocation"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

Here is my code:

```js
  async getGridPointApiUrl() {
    const position = await this.getPosition();
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log([latitude, longitude, position.coords.accuracy]);
  }

  getPosition() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        resolve,
        reject,
        {
          maximumAge: 0,
          timeout: Infinity,
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
    });
  }
```

When I run this, I get an accuracy of 5 metres. No way is that right! The returned coordinates are a good 10 miles off. Though, whether or not `enableHighAccuracy` is true of false, I get the same results. Is that suppose to happen? I was testing this on the Chromium based [Brave Browser](https://brave.com/).

I decided to check the same code on Firefox, et voila the coordinates returned were way better and the accuracy reading seemed correct. However, the boolean `enableHighAccuracy` similarly had no effect on the accuracy displayed in Firefox either.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to get the accuracy to be as good on Brave as it is on Firefox at least?

Comment: Documentation states - *The PositionOptions.enableHighAccuracy property is a Boolean that indicates the application would like to receive the best possible results. If true **and if the device is able to provide a more accurate position**, it will do so.* - so, accuracy depends on the device, not the browser

Comment: Then how do I explain the fact that I am getting different errors (and coordinates) with different browsers on the same device?

Comment: what is the device?

Comment: so it's a laptop ... and how does the laptop know where it is?

Comment: Just like you, I read the documentation before posting the question. The browser asks for permission before "accessing location" and I allow it. Beyond that, I thought it should just be using the machine's GPS.

Comment: I deleted that on purpose :), don't all modern laptops come with a GPS? I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04. So I am guessing however GNU/Linux does it.

Comment: *don't all modern laptops come with a GPS?* no - do any?

Comment: As for Ubuntu - don't know how it gets its location ... there are methods without GPS - google streetview cars used to (or maybe still do) also map (very approcimately) wifi SSID's - so it's possible to get location from local wifis - other mapping solutions have this ability too - perhaps different browsers use different methods/providers hence the different location